Gurgling Sound At Back of Fridge
This is about a 10-year old built-in Siemens refrigerator. Recently, I've noticed it seems to run longer and more loudly than it used to, with a noticeable gurgle. Food is still kept cool though.
I pulled it out to take a look and/or clean the coils, but I don't see any obvious damage. I've uploaded a video, but the sound isn't so clear.

This really needs more information to properly diagnose. Unfortunately, that pretty much requires pulling it apart for troubleshooting.

Is the defrost cycle working properly? A bad heater or other defrost component is common for older refrigerators. There could be related problems like a part/fully blocked drain. The heater is easy to test, but usually requires some disassembly to access.
